# Standard practice for navigation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a project in WPF and I'm not really familiar with it.

I have built the program, but I'm dissatisfied with the navigation.
It's a simple program, a couple of buttons which takes you to different pages. Changing page have I solved by  the following:

```
            Menu main = new Menu();
            App.Current.MainWindow = main;
            this.Close();
            main.Show();
```

This is probably very incorrect. Any knowledge of standard practice for code behind or MVVM?

Comment: google Frame/Navigation Window

Comment: There are two ways -> using Frame or just simply hide/show content depending on the current view.

Comment: Add a constructor in your WFP window which takes a `window` type as parameter and then handle the referrer inside of the active window. For example, when you dispose it, then show the referrer prior to disposing it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where i used the standard method Visibilty and changed it between collapsed and visible.

So three pages => 3 Containers

- Button1
  -- Show Container1 Collapse Container2,3
- Button2
  -- Show Container2 Collapse Container1,3
- Button3
  -- Show Container3 Collapse Container1,2

If you have a lot of pages this is not a nice way to do it, but for 2 to 5 pages its ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Paul Stovell's blog post for more information about the common navigations options that are available in WPF: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

You could implement an interface in the view where the Frame is defined and then inject the view model with this interface to be able to use the Frame for navigation. There is an example available here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b09bbfd4-05ee-4f62-b5df-77c0792e6ad7/how-to-refresh-the-frame-using-a-view-model-in-c?forum=wpf